# Java.awt.geom.RectangularShape support on GAE

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm using the Apache POI library for manipulating a PowerPoint file.
It works great on GAE for inspecting the contents of a PPTX file.
However, if I try to change the contents of a PowerPoint file I get the following GAE error:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.awt.geom.RectangularShape is a restricted class. Please see the Google App Engine developer's guide for more details.
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.shared.stub.java.awt.geom.RectangularShape.(RectangularShape.java)
    at org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFSimpleShape.getAnchor(XSLFSimpleShape.java:176)

Has anyone had any experience getting around this issue or similar java.awt issues on GAE?
I'm considering hacking the Apache POI source but would rather some kind of native support of java.awt in GAE.  I've done some research and:

1)  A lot of issues have been raised on GAE for java.awt support and it has been accepted as an issue. Was wondering if this had progressed internally?  It was accepted August 2011.

2)  There is a project: http://code.google.com/p/appengine-awt/ that is a pure java implementation of java.awt.  Does this support java.awt.geom.RectangularShape I wonder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've managed to workaround this for other interested Apache POI users using GAE.
You can do some manipulations on a pre-defined PowerPoint template just avoid any of the methods that require using the underlying java.awt libraries (which are restricted on GAE).  My issue was using the createSlide() and importContent() methods. I only need to modify the text so operating on the in-memory version of the PPT file using:

```
XSLFShape[] shapes = slide.getShapes();
    for (XSLFShape shape : shapes) {
        if (shape instanceof XSLFTextShape) {
            XSLFTextShape textShape = (XSLFTextShape)shape;

            switch (shape.getShapeId()) 
            case 1:
                textShape.setText("1st text box");
```

Solves my problem.

Plea to Google - Please provide an API for doing direct manipulations of Google Docs/Presentations. Currently the only solution is to download Google presentation to GAE (in-memory), use Apache POI for the manipulation, and upload as a different Google presentation.